# get XML element attribute when value of sibling attribute is particular value using elementtree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file similar to below:

```
<data>
    <ruleset>
        <ruleset_mapping>
            <rule id="foo" />
            <action cd_result="Pass" fg_continue="No" fg_disable="0">
                <cd_alert>foo</cd_alert>
                <id_outcome>APPROVE</id_outcome>
                <tx_message_application />
            </action>
            <cd_level>Application</cd_level>
        </ruleset_mapping>
        <ruleset_mapping>
            <rule id="bar" />
            <action cd_result="Fail" fg_continue="No" fg_disable="0">
                <cd_alert>bar</cd_alert>
                <id_outcome />
                <tx_message_application />
            </action>
            <cd_level>Application</cd_level>
        </ruleset_mapping>
    </ruleset>
</data>
```

I want to extract the value of the `cd_result` attribute from the `action` element, but only where the value of the `id` attribute in the sibling `rule` element is `foo`.

So, in the above, I want to get the value `Pass`. I think the result should be found using something similar to:

```
for element in root.findall(".//ruleset_mapping/rule"):
    if element.attrib['id'] == 'foo':
        print(root.findall(".//ruleset_mapping/action['@cd_result']"))
```

...but I cannot get it quite right. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it. Iterate over the `ruleset_mapping` elements.

```py
for rs_map in root.findall(".//ruleset_mapping"):
    rule_id = rs_map.find("rule").get("id")
    cd_result = rs_map.find("action").get("cd_result")
                         
    if rule_id == "foo":
        print(cd_result)
```